# Regular expression Positive lookbehind, ignore first 2 words

Tags: regex

I have the following sentence: total 10 item(s) 26,50

I want to extract the number 26,50 based on the word "total". I came this far with a Positive Lookbehind but I'm stuck now. `(?<=total )(.*)(?=\d)`

Comment: Is it for .NET? Where do you use the regex? In some program of yours or a tool? I ask because the best idea here is perhaps, to just use a capturing group: [`^total\s+.*?(\d+(?:,\d+)?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/fW4yN9/1).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need lookbehind. Use groups:

https://regex101.com/r/oC0dM3/2

```
total\s+(?P<COUNT>\d+)\s+item(?:\(s\))?\s+(?P<PRICE>\d+(?:,\d+)?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Many Regex engine does not support variable variable length Look behind, in those cases your Regex would be pretty inefficient if you use lookbehind.

Use pattern grouping instead:

```
^total[^)]+\)\s+(.*)$
```

The only captured group here is your desired portion.

- `^total[^)]+\)\s+` matches upto the last whitespace before the desired pattern
- `(.*)$` gets our desired portion

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vL2lP7/7)